# C# take all child nodes at one time

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to take 2 first row (header) of a wikitable. In particular is the table under "Lista Episodi" at the following link: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episodi_di_Dragon_Ball_Super
The first row is:

```
<table class="wikitable" style="width:auto">
 <tbody> 
  <tr>
    <th style="width:auto;white-space:nowrap" rowspan="2">Nº
    </th>
    <td style="background:#eaecf0;text-align:left;width:auto" rowspan="2">
     <b><a title="Lingua italiana" href="/wiki/Lingua_italiana">Titolo italiano</a>
     </b> 
     <br>
     <b>
      <a title="Lingua giapponese" href="/wiki/Lingua_giapponese">Giapponese</a>
     </b> 
     「
     <i>
      <b><a title="Kanji" href="/wiki/Kanji">Kanji</a></b></i>
     」 - 
     <i>
      <b>
       <a title="Rōmaji" href="/wiki/R%C5%8Dmaji">Rōmaji</a>
      </b>
     </i>
      - 
     <b>
      <a title="Traduzione" href="/wiki/Traduzione">Traduzione letterale</a>
     </b>
    </td>
    <th colspan="2">In onda</th>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a working code that can take correctly the entire header and put it inside a List:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        string page = "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episodi_di_Modern_Family_(prima_stagione)";
        string page1 = "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episodi_di_Dragon_Ball_Super";
        StreamReader reader;
        reader = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(page1).GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);               
        doc.Load(reader);
List<List<string>> header = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='wikitable']").Descendants("tr")
            .Where(ld => ld.Elements("th").Count() > 0)
            .Select(ld => ld.Elements("th").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList()).ToList();
```

Unfortunately in this table there is also a td-node instead only th-node even if it's a row of header. The previous code can read only th-node.
How can I take the 2 th-node and the td-node at the same time? I tried something like:

```
List<List<string>> header = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='wikitable']").Descendants("tbody")
            .Where(ld => ld.Elements("tr").Count() > 0)
            .Select(ld => ld.Elements("tr").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList()).ToList();
```

It gets all 3 child nodes but the 3 contents are putted all togheter inside a single string. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You taking a content of `tr` tag but you need to flatten it down. Try something like this:

```
List<List<string>> header2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='wikitable']")
    .Descendants("tr")
    .Select(x=>x.ChildNodes
        .Select(c=>c.InnerText.Trim())
        .Where(y=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y))
        .ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You can't add a second Elements: "HtmlNode doesn't contain a definition for Elements"

Comment: ahh yes you using HtmlDoc not XDoc. Can you create minimal example so I would be able to recreate issue?

Comment: @Allanon87 Thanks. I have updated my answer. You can try to use `ChildNodes` to flatten down the inner elements of all `tr` tags. I hope that will help you at least to get an ide how it works.